# Why doesn't my compare work between char and int in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
char c = '0';
int i = 0;
System.out.println(c == i);
```

Why does this always returns false?

Comment: If `System.out.println(data);` is not executed, then (obviously) `c` does not equal `s`.

Comment: @BartKiers yeah they are not equal..but the value printed on the above statement is the same for s and c..

Comment: What is the result of `System.out.println((int)c + " " + s);`?

Comment: @saskoch - See Ernest's answer below. The *textual representations* are the same; the *values* are not.

Answer (score 23):

Although this question is very unclear, I am pretty sure the poster wants to know why this prints `false`:

```
char c = '0';
int i = 0;
System.out.println(c == i);
```

The answer is because every printable character is assigned a unique code number, and that's the value that a `char` has when treated as an `int`. The code number for the character `0` is decimal 48, and obviously 48 is not equal to 0.

Why aren't the character codes for the digits equal to the digits themselves? Mostly because the first few codes, especially `0`, are too special to be used for such a mundane purpose.

Answer (score 9):

The char c = '0' has the ascii code 48. This number is compared to s, not '0'. If you want to compare c with s you can either do:

```
if(c == s) // compare ascii code of c with s
```

This will be true if c = '0' and s = 48.

or

```
if(c == s + '0') // compare the digit represented by c 
                 // with the digit represented by s
```

This will be true if c = '0' and s = 0.

Answer (score 1):

The char and int value can not we directly compare we need to apply casting. So need to casting char to string and after string will pars into integer

```
char c='0';
int i=0;
```

Answer is like

```
String c = String.valueOf(c);

System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(c) == i)
```

It will return true;

Hope it will help you

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You're saying that `s` is an Integer and `c` (from what I see) is a Char.. so there you, that's the problem: `Integer vs. Char comparation`.