# Mybatis executed the <if> tag incorrectly，

Tags: java, mybatis

I wish to execute the following SQL

```sql
  select  count(*) from cl_class where user_id = 48
```

I use mybatis to execute SQL,48 is not null and not equal '' and not equal '0'
ClClassMapper.xml

```xml
 <select id="selectCount" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
    select  count(*) from cl_class
    <if test="userId != null and userId != '' and userId != '0'" >
      where user_id = #{userId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
    </if>
  </select>
```

this is interface method
ClClassMapper.java

```java
Integer selectCount(@Param(value = "userId") int userId);
```

test code

```java
    @Test
    public void mybatisProcessTest() throws Exception{
        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-config.xml");
        SqlSessionFactoryBuilder builder= new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();
        SqlSessionFactory factory = builder.build(reader,"development");
        SqlSession session = factory.openSession();
        Integer clClass = session.selectOne("com.jyg.demo.mapper.ClClassMapper.selectCount", 48);
        session.commit();
        System.out.println("count=" + clClass.toString());
    }
```

my Expected value is

```java
count=4
```

but print

```java
count=5
```

and strangely, when I changed 48 to 2, the result was as expected

```java
    // Integer clClass = session.selectOne("com.jyg.demo.mapper.ClClassMapper.selectCount", 48);
    Integer clClass = session.selectOne("com.jyg.demo.mapper.ClClassMapper.selectCount", 2);
    //  clClass = 1
```

my data

```sql
id  user_id class_name  create_time update_time is_delete
1   48  java    2021-09-03 14:50:30 2021-09-13 14:46:29 0
2   48  mysql   2021-09-03 14:50:30 2021-09-13 14:46:32 0
3   48  linux   2021-09-03 14:50:30 2021-09-13 14:46:32 0
4   48  redis   2021-09-03 14:50:30 2021-09-13 14:46:32 0
5   2   spring  2021-09-03 14:50:30 2021-09-13 14:43:49 0

INSERT INTO `test_db`.`cl_class`(`id`, `user_id`, `class_name`, `create_time`, `update_time`, `is_delete`) VALUES (1, 48, 'java', '2021-09-03 14:50:30', '2021-09-13 14:46:29', 0);
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`cl_class`(`id`, `user_id`, `class_name`, `create_time`, `update_time`, `is_delete`) VALUES (2, 48, 'mysql', '2021-09-03 14:50:30', '2021-09-13 14:46:32', 0);
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`cl_class`(`id`, `user_id`, `class_name`, `create_time`, `update_time`, `is_delete`) VALUES (3, 48, 'linux', '2021-09-03 14:50:30', '2021-09-13 14:46:32', 0);
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`cl_class`(`id`, `user_id`, `class_name`, `create_time`, `update_time`, `is_delete`) VALUES (4, 48, 'redis', '2021-09-03 14:50:30', '2021-09-13 14:46:32', 0);
INSERT INTO `test_db`.`cl_class`(`id`, `user_id`, `class_name`, `create_time`, `update_time`, `is_delete`) VALUES (5, 2, 'spring', '2021-09-03 14:50:30', '2021-09-13 14:43:49', 0);
```

mybaits-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <properties resource="jdbc.properties"/>
    <settings>
        <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J" />
        <setting name= "mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true" />
        <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false"/>

    </settings>

    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.jyg.demo.domain" />
    </typeAliases>

    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="${driver}"/>
                <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
                <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
                <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <package name="com.jyg.demo.mapper"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Comparing int and char don't work like you're expecting.  Just remove the single quotes `and userId != '0'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232826/why-doesnt-my-compare-work-between-char-and-int-in-java

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why is it as expected when userId becomes 2?

Comment: I have found the answer. When the 0 of the char type is cast to the long type, 48 will be output ，(long)'0' = 48. In addition, I would like to know how ongl syntax works during this period?